# Check if item with particular value of a property is present in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have a website that is required to read data from an external txt file..I had put that file in the App_data folder and read the data from that file using this code

the txt file contain 3 texts.. which are: kevin123 INFO102lec INFO102k

```
   protected void logInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string usernameListString = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/usernameFile.txt");

    string[] userAray = usernameListString.Split(' ');
    bool usernameExists = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < userAray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (usernameTextBox.Text == userAray[i])
        {
            welcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome" + userAray[i];
        }

        if (usernameTextBox.Text != userAray[i])
        {
            welcomeLabel.Text = "unknown user";
        }

        usernameExists = true;

    }
```

I want to  write a `for` loop that goes through each item of `userArray`. At the end of the loop, set `usernameExists` to true only if the username entered in the username text box is present in the array.
I coded something which when I type 1 of those name in the textbox?? it give an welcome label if the name doesn exist?? and vice versa!

IS anything wrong with my code above?

Comment: It looks that you started to do this and then you stopped for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
bool usernameExists = false;
for (int  i = 0; i < userAray.Length; i++)
{
    if (userAray[i] == "kevin123")
    {
        usernameExists = true;
        break; // stop checking more values
    }
}
```

Or more simply:

```
bool usernameExists = userAray.Contains("kevin123");
```

Or if you want to check whether the array contains any of several values:

```
string[] userNamesToSearchFor = new[] { "kevin123", "INFO102lec", "INFO102k" };
bool usernameExists = userAray.Intersect(userNamesToSearchFor).Any();
```

---

Regarding your update, the problem is that you're trying to update your labels as you're looping through the array. You need to first determine if the username exists in the array (`usernameExists`) and *then* set the labels indicating the result, for example:

```
for (int  i = 0; i < userAray.Length; i++)
{
    if (userAray[i] == usernameTextBox.Text)
    {
        usernameExists = true;
        break; // stop checking more values
    }
}

if (usernameExists)
{
    welcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome " + usernameTextBox.Text;
}
else 
{
    welcomeLabel.Text = "unknown user";
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to check for 3 names: `kevin123`, `INFO102lec`, or `INFO102k`

Comment: thanks....and how do i code when i type 1 of those name in the textbox?? it give an error if the name doesnt exist?? and vice versa!

Comment: ok, i have a text box name: usernameTextBox! and when i type kevin123 in the textbox, the loop started to search for that name..and give an label :) Thanks for your help

Comment: @PéBin Unfortunately, that still doesn't help. I would need to know exactly what code you're using and where you're seeing that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq for this:

```
usernameExists = userArray.Any(x => x == usernameTextBox.Text);
```

Also, in your example, you declare `userAray` as a string array.. yet you use it like a single string.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
protected void logInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string usernameListString = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~") 
      + "/App_Data/usernameFile.txt");

string[] userAray = usernameListString.Split(' ');
bool usernameExists = false;
for (int  i = 0; i < userAray.Length; i++)
{
    if (userAray[i]==usernameTextBox.Text)
    {
        welcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome" + userAray[i];
        usernameExists = true;
    }
    else
    {
        welcomeLabel.Text = "unknown user";
    }        
}
```

Comment: thanks but i also would like to know how to code when i type kevin123 in the usernameTextBox and it tell me that kevin123 is exist in the system? thanks

Comment: just replace **"kevin123"** with **usernameTextBox.Text** in if condition. then show the output in label.

Comment: and add code in else section for not matching the name in array.

Comment: i did what you did....But it always come to the result that the name doesnt exsist ==> label.text = unknown user

Comment: is is like this?
if (userAray[i] == usernameTextBox.Text)
            {
                welcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome " + userAray[i];
                usernameExists = true;
            }

            if (userAray[i] != usernameTextBox.Text)
            {
                welcomeLabel.Text = "Unknown User";
            }

Comment: @PéBin haha.. dear if condition should be like this **if (userAray[i]==usernameTextBox.Text)**. try this

Comment: thanks you so much .. but im kind of new to programming ...:(

Comment: It is ok @PéBin we all start like this. just keep it up :-)

Comment: if this answer helps you then don't forget to check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need `==` and try ReadAllLines to read all lines from the file

```
string[] userAray = File.ReadAllLines();
if (userAray[i] == "kevin123" || userAray[i] == "INFO102lec" || userAray[i] == "INFO102k") 
{
   usernameExists = true;
   break; 
}
```

Single `=` is used for assignment. `==` is for comparision

Comment: Hrmm.. I just figured that was a typo by the OP.. since the code is half baked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    bool usernameExists = false;
    for (int  i = 0; i < userAray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (userAray == "kevin123")
        {
          usernameExists =true;
        }
    }
```